# HERE Maps API to retrieve the hierarchical administrative groups per country

Tags: here-api

I am new to HERE MAP and GIS, is there an API to retrieve the administrative groups per parent, i.e:

- Api to get all States by Country
- then to get all Counties per State
- then all Cities per County
- finally all Districts per City

All this without any coordinates - the result is needed to perform a cascade search in my database by selecting country, state and county, not related with any position.